# Upsert nested document throwing mapping error elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to do upsert during update but I don't know why I can't do it with java API.

Here is my problem:

When I am using scripting, I can update my document as expected like this :

```
esClientManager.getEsClient().prepareUpdate(index, type, id).setScript("ctx._source.location =" + json)
```

But when I try to use the setDoc method to be able to use setDocAsUpsert after I get error. Here is the request with setDoc:

```
 esClientManager.getEsClient().prepareUpdate(index, type, id).setDoc("location", json).setDocAsUpsert(true);
```

ELasticsearch throws the following error:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: object mapping for [type] tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:467)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:515)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:462)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareCreate(InternalIndexShard.java:363)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:406)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardUpdateOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:501)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:228)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:556)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:426)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The location object that I am updating is a nested document with the following mapping:

```
"properties": {
                "location": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties":{
                        "point":{"type":"geo_point"}                
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any idea why it is not working ?